# In App Purchase - can get product info but can't connect to itunes for purchase

Tags: iphone, storekit

I'm trying to make "In App Purchase " works in my iphone app.

I created some products and a few test accounts in itunes connect.

I have no problem to retreive the products data (prices etc..) but when I try to make a payment 
- I am asked to log in 
- I use a test account
-> the transaction always fail with the following error :

failedTransaction with error : Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible" UserInfo=0x65d02a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Connexion à l’iTunes Store impossible}

I tried with several products and test account (even in other stores like us) but I still get the same error...

NB : I think it worked fine the first time I tried but never still

Any idea will be welcome !

Thanks

Comment: stupid question; are you using a real device or simulator?

Comment: after login I can see the pop-up that asks me to confirm my purchase. The error comes after that.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just scoured my code until I found my mistake. I was so certain everything was fine, but it was not. When I requested product information from the store, I used the correct Product Identifier:

```
self.productRequest= [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: @"com.popculturesoft.RC_vCar.fullVersion"]] autorelease];
```

However, when I went to create the payment, I used the incorrect Product Identifier:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.popculturesoft.RC_vCar_Lite.fullVerson"];
```

Using the product Identifier for the payment is not the correct way to do it, although it allows you to do it. It is better to use an SKProduct object. (I had set the fullProduct property earlier in the code:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.fullProduct];
```

I was absolutely certain that the store was down, and that was the problem. But the next day I decided to start from the beginning of the process, as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html. This is when I found that my incorrect Product Identifier was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread.  It seems to be a problem with the Sandbox.  Lot's of people having this issue-

[iPhone storekit sandbox stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522899/iphone-storekit-sandbox-stopped-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and in my case the problem was that I had a test user account with the same name as a real Apple ID account.  I resolved the problem by creating a different test user account.