# iPad In App Purchase fails with SKErrorPaymentCancelled and "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone storekit sandbox stopped working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522899/iphone-storekit-sandbox-stopped-working)

Hi.

I updated today to version 3.2.2 of the iPad iOS and I noticed that my In App Purchase testing was not working.
I am using a test account and everyhing was working until now (our app is already live since june and the real in app purchase works), but today I wanted to make a test purchase with the same product and test user that I always used and now it's not working.

The problem is as follows:

1. I start the in app purchase.
2. Confirm the purchase and sign in with the test user.
3. Because this is a non-consumable product the App Store notifies me, that I have already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded.
4. Press OK.
5. Up until now the transaction observer got a transaction with the transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased and the user got his/her in app feature.
6. But now the transactionState is SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed with the error:

   > Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 UserInfo=0x2debe0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Code=2 means SKErrorPaymentCancelled. WTF? This should happen if the user canceled the transaction, not in a real error. This is very misleading. I am not supposed to show this as an error because most of the time this is called if a user really cancels his/her purchase and there is no way to determine whether this error was caused by the user or by the App Store.

Everything is set up correctly, as I mentioned the in app purchase testing worked and I get the products as valid. Also I didn't change the code handling the in app purchase.

The error must be somewhere on the App Store side.

Does anyone else had this problem?

Thank you.

### Update

I tested the app on the iPhone (it's a universal app) running iOS 4.0.2 and the error looks like this:

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x2620e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

The Code=0 is SKErrorUnknown and the app displays an error to the user.
So it seems that iOS 4.0.2 handles this problem better than iOS 3.2.2.

Comment: Hi, I am observing exactly the same problem since yesterday within my iphone app in development.

It seems others observing this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520539/in-app-purchase-can-get-product-info-but-cant-connect-to-itunes-for-purchase

Comment: I will test it now with the iPhone version of the app to see if the problem is occurring there, too. I thought that maybe the 3.2.2 update was causing it, but it looks like it's device independent.

Comment: Also have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522899

Answer (score 0):

I tested again and fortunately it seems that the problem is gone. I can test the in app purchase without any problems.

I hope it works now for others, too.

Comment: How have you solved it. I can't test it on simulator.

Comment: Hello Victor, if you use iOS Simulator from XCode 4.2.1 or newer you can test the in app purchases on the simulator, too.